# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: layerView.createQuery is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, arcgis

```
Layer.fromArcGISServerUrl("").then(function (layer) {
                map.add(layer);
                view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false; // <- disable view popup auto open
                view.on("click", function (event) { // <- listen to view click event
                    if (event.button === 0) { // <- check that was left button or touch
                        view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function (layerView) {
                            const query = layerView.layer.createQuery();
                            query.geometry = view.toMap(event);
                            query.distance = 1;
                            query.units = "meters";
                            layerView.queryFeatures(query).then(
                                response => {
                                    document.getElementById("infomap").innerText = JSON.stringify(response.features);
                                    console.error(response);
                                },
                                err => {
                                    document.getElementById("infomap").innerText = "Query returns an error, check console to see what happen!.";
                                    console.error(err);
                                }
                            );
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

I want to get info about pop up's using ArcGis in React and I get the mistake that createQuery is not a function. I dont understand why I have this err. Help please

Comment: Please be clearer about what you've tried and the behavior that you're facing

Comment: What does console.log({layerView}) return if you put it above "const query..." ?

Comment: my console return Object

Comment: check if you can see 'layer' in its properties, and if this layer obj has a createQuery property

Comment: Ok, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-Layer.html), I understand that `layer` is a base class, and there are multiple types of `layers` that extend that class. The `createQuery` method is not on the base class so it might be that you are calling `createQuery` on layer type that does not have that method implemented.

What does `layerView.layer.constructor.name` give you in the console?

Comment: It's return "v"

Comment: damn, it means that it's mimified.. try `JSON.stringify(layerView.layer)` and post here the result

Comment: {"id":"181bf5ced0c-layer-5","showLegend":true,"listMode":"show","title":"MS MAK 3","url":"","visibility":true,"refreshInterval":0,"layerType":"ArcGISMapServiceLayer","minScale":0,"maxScale":0,"timeAnimation":true}

Comment: Sorry, can't show url

Comment: so you don't have the `createQuery` function